# How does this inequality hold? $|d(x,x_0)-d(y,x_0)|\le d(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I came across this during some reading: $|d(x,x_0)-d(y,x_0)|\le d(x,y)$. I can't seem to figure out why it holds. Here $d$ is a metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the triangle inequality we know that:

$$
d(x,x_0) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,x_0)
$$

Can you use this fact to achieve that $ |d(x,x_0) - d(y,x_0)| \leq |d(x,y)| $ ? Once you know this, recall that $d$ is a non-negative function...

Answer (score 1):

Combine the following two applications of the triangle inequality:
\begin{align}
d(x,x_0) &\le d(x,y) + d(y, x_0)
\\
d(y, x_0) &\le d(x,y) + d(x, x_0)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Use the triangle inequality to show that $d(x,y)\ge d(x,x_0)-d(y,x_0)$ *and* $d(x,y)\ge d(y,x_0)-d(x,x_0)$.